# Update the TextView of an home-screen widget on-clicking

Tags: android, onclick, textview, android-widget

In my app I am keeping track of a counter, which can be incremented by clicking on a widget button.

I wanted to give the user some feedback that his clicking has added one to the counter - so i tried to add a textView above the widget button. Is there a way to update the presented number after clicking?

My code (currently shows an outdated value of the counter...):

```
for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {

    Intent incCounter = new Intent(context, WidgetBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, incCounter, 0); //braodcasting to a counter changing module

    RemoteViews ButtonCounterView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.home_screen_widget);
    ButtonCounterView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widgetCounterButton, pendingIntent);

    String updatedCounter = String.valueOf(countersMap.getInt(todaysDate.getDate(), 0));
    ButtonCounterView.setTextViewText(R.id.widgetCounter, updatedCounter);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, ButtonCounterView);
}
```

Comment: update textview contents and then update widget

Comment: What do you mean by that? where in my code should i add the setTextViewText, and where the setOnClickPendingIntent? @nomag

Answer (score 1):

You need to update remoteviews contents inside `WidgetBroadcastReceiver` and then refresh the widget as below:

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplication(), YourWidget.class);
int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is.

Add and onClickStatement to your button where the user clicks (in the xml folder):

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:text="Click me!"
    android:onClick="myMethod" />
```

Then on your actual class, just create the following:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myMethod();
    }
});
```

Then, myMethod() will basically do something like:

```
textView.setText("Enter text that says user has added one to the counter")
```

Comment: Thanks! Are you sure that it is relevant to home-screen widgets? Because the widget class won't allow me use the findViewById. Also I think you can only use setOnClickPendingIntent and not OnClickListener on widget, but not sure... I'll check it anyways

Comment: its not relevant to notifcation at all.

Comment: I tried to help, looks like I was mistaken. I am sorry for that buddy